# How to get followers and following with Twitter/Social framework in iOS

Tags: ios, api, twitter, slrequest

How can I get all **followers** and **following** from a user's Twitter account.

I get followers and following counts. However I need usernames of followers and following users.

Here my code.

```
- (void) getAccountInfo
{
    ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

    [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error){
        if (granted) {

            NSArray *accounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

            // Check if the users has setup at least one Twitter account

            if (accounts.count > 0)
            {
                ACAccount *twitterAccount = [accounts objectAtIndex:0];

                // Creating a request to get the info about a user on Twitter

                SLRequest *twitterInfoRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json"] parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:twitterAccount.username forKey:@"screen_name"]];
                [twitterInfoRequest setAccount:twitterAccount];

                // Making the request

                [twitterInfoRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                        // Check if we reached the reate limit

                        if ([urlResponse statusCode] == 429) {
                            NSLog(@"Rate limit reached");
                            return;
                        }

                        // Check if there was an error

                        if (error) {
                            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                            return;
                        }

                        // Check if there is some response data

                        if (responseData) {

                            NSError *error = nil;
                            NSArray *TWData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];


                            // Filter the preferred data

                            NSString *screen_name = [(NSDictionary *)TWData objectForKey:@"screen_name"];
                            NSString *name = [(NSDictionary *)TWData objectForKey:@"name"];

                            int followers = [[(NSDictionary *)TWData objectForKey:@"followers_count"] integerValue];
                            int following = [[(NSDictionary *)TWData objectForKey:@"friends_count"] integerValue];


                        }
                    });
                }];
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"No access granted");
        }
    }];

}
```

Comment: This code not working because app is crash while executing 
    [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) line 
having reason "reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString accessKeys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance "

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Getting list of followers

To get list of followers, change the `URL` you are requesting to:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/list.json
```

It returns a cursored collection of user objects for users following the specified user.

### Getting list of followed users

To get list of the users you follow, change the `URL` you are requesting to:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/list.json
```

It returns a cursored collection of user objects for every user the specified user is following (otherwise known as their "friends").

I used your code to test it and it works. Based on [REST API v1.1 Resources](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Criexe API, if you don't want use API.
https://github.com/criexe/api/wiki/Social-Networks-Page-Stats-API

**Example:**

GET `https://api.criexe.com/social/pageStats?twitter=microsoft`

```
{
   "twitter":{
      "user":"microsoft",
      "followers":8293150
   },
   "total":8293150
}
```